# Membership.ValidateUser return: null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used AspNetSqlMembershipProvider to create a login portal

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
 <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" connectionStringName="MembershipDB" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" applicationName="php" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

However I could not login with the username and password I created, I stepped into the code and found Membership.ValidateUser return: null

Here is the code:

```
   protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
   {
            bool UserAuthenticated = false;
            MembershipProvider AuthenticationProviderUsed = null;
            RoleProvider roleProvider = Roles.Providers["SqlRoleProvider"];
            // Try authenticating the user against each membership provider
            foreach (MembershipProvider membershipProvider in Membership.Providers)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (membershipProvider.ValidateUser(loginInitial.UserName, loginInitial.Password)) // here got null.
                    {
```

I checked the database. Both username and password are there.
Thanks for help.

## update: return false.

Then  `MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(loginInitial.UserName);`user return `null`.

## update again: more code,

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
            bool UserAuthenticated = false;
            MembershipProvider AuthenticationProviderUsed = null;
            RoleProvider roleProvider = Roles.Providers["SqlRoleProvider"];
            // Try authenticating the user against each membership provider
            foreach (MembershipProvider membershipProvider in Membership.Providers)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (membershipProvider.ValidateUser(loginInitial.UserName, loginInitial.Password))
                    {
                        if (base.ConfigSettings.OperatingMode == ConfigurationSettingValues.OperatingModes.NoAccess)
                        {
                            if (!roleProvider.IsUserInRole(loginInitial.UserName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminRole"]))
                            {
                                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        MembershipUser usrInfo = Membership.GetUser(loginInitial.UserName);
                        if (membershipProvider.Name == "ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider")
                        {
                            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInitial.UserName, loginInitial.RememberMeSet);
                            UserAuthenticated = true;
                            AuthenticationProviderUsed = membershipProvider;
                            break;
                       }
                        else
                        {
                            
                            Int16 daysSincePwdChange = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Subtract(usrInfo.LastPasswordChangedDate).TotalDays);

                            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInitial.UserName, loginInitial.RememberMeSet);

                            if (daysSincePwdChange > SecurityUtils.DefaultPasswordExpiryInDays || usrInfo.Comment == "ChangePassword")
                            {
                                 e.Authenticated = false;
                                Response.Redirect("~/admin/ChangePassword.aspx?UserName=" + Server.UrlEncode(loginInitial.UserName));
                             }
                            else
                            {

                                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInitial.UserName, loginInitial.RememberMeSet);
                                UserAuthenticated = true;
                                AuthenticationProviderUsed = membershipProvider;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
              
                   }
                    else
                    {
                        // See if the user is locked out
                        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(loginInitial.UserName);
                        if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut)
                        {
                            ErrorMessage.Text = "Your account is currently locked out.  Please contact the system administrator.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid user name and/or password";
                            //Response.Write("Invalid User Name or Password");
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                       LoggingLibrary.LogException(this.Logger, Context, ex, ex);

                }
            }
```

The eror message is:"Invalid user name and/or password"

Comment: MembershipProvider.ValidateUser returns a bool. You probably mean it returned false, not null.

Comment: [Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) can only return true or false.

Comment: Even if you have not shown the complete code, i assume that you only call Membership.GetUser if ValidateUser returns true. So i don't understand your updated question where you say that ValidateUser  returns false but Membership.GetUser is null(you shouldn't get to this point normally).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check if the user exists in the database.
You might be using two different databases, one locally and one for production.
Can you show your connection string for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider?

*** EDIT ***
I am no expert with connection strings, but it seems to me that you are running against a sql compact db. I would connect to the db using server explorer from vs or sql manager and check the aspnet_Users table and verify if your user is present.

Are you testing locally or on a production machine? If on production, did it work locally?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
  <add name="MembershipDB" connectionString="Data Source=AllDB;Initial Catalog=PortalAccess;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=php" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: There is a field "IsApproved" in the table "aspnet_Membership". Once it is true, then everything is fine. It is false by default.